# PHP rendering two columns, but I need three columns

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have some php that creates two columns of website content categories with child articles from that category. I've tried messing with the code that inserts the  after two posts are listed, but it's not working (because I don't know what I'm doing). The current php renders as follows:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="column col-half">...</div>
<div class="column col-half">...</div>
</div>
```

I'd like it to render as:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="column col-third">...</div>
<div class="column col-third">...</div>
<div class="column col-third">...</div>
</div>
```

Here is the theme's code that renders the HTML:

```
$st_categories = get_categories($st_hp_cat_args); 
$st_categories = wp_list_filter($st_categories,array('parent'=>0));
if ($st_categories) {
    foreach($st_categories as $st_category) { 
        $st_cat_counter++;

        if ((!is_int($st_cat_counter / 2)) && $st_cat_counter != 1) { 
            echo '</div><div class="row">';
        } elseif ($st_cat_counter == 1) {
            echo '<div class="row">';
        }

        echo '<div class="column col-half '. $st_cat_counter.'">';
        echo '<h3> <a href="' . get_category_link( $st_category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( 'View all posts in %s', 'framework' ), $st_category->name ) . '" ' . '>' .     $st_category->name.'</a>';

        if (of_get_option('st_hp_cat_counts') == '1') {
            echo '<span class="cat-count">(' . $st_category->count.')</span>';  
        }

        echo '</h3>';
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change `$st_cat_counter / 2` to `$st_cat_counter / 3` and adjust your CSS accordingly.

Comment: @ceejayoz That was the first thing I tried before posting here, but that doesn't work. It renders content in one column in the first row, then two columns in the second row. It repeats that pattern down the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change just a couple of things (I improved the code style in terms of lines and indentation as well):

```
$st_categories = get_categories($st_hp_cat_args); 
$st_categories = wp_list_filter($st_categories,array('parent'=>0));
if ($st_categories) {
    foreach($st_categories as $st_category) { 
        $st_cat_counter++;

        if (1 === $st_cat_counter % 3 && $st_cat_counter !== 1) { // change 2 -> 3 and use mod operator %
            echo '</div><div class="row">';
        } elseif ($st_cat_counter == 1) {
            echo '<div class="row">';
        }
        echo '<div class="column col-third '. $st_cat_counter.'">'; // half -> third
        echo '<h3> <a href="' . get_category_link( $st_category->term_id ) . '" title="' .     sprintf( __( 'View all posts in %s', 'framework' ), $st_category->name ) . '" ' . '>' .     $st_category->name.'</a>';
        if (of_get_option('st_hp_cat_counts') == '1') {
            echo '<span class="cat-count">(' . $st_category->count.')</span>';  
        }
        echo '</h3>';
```

Comment: Would it be more appropriate to use the 'mod' function for checking the end of 'group of 3 lines? i.e _'$st_cat_counter % 3 === 0'_ rather than _'is_int($st_cat_counter / 3)'_.

Comment: Yeah, it would be better. I've tried to fix it above. It looks like the counter is starting at 1, though, which could be weird. I think the above will work.

Comment: Thanks guys. The latest update almost works but it renders two columns in the first row, then three columns in the following rows

Comment: Let me know if there's php that appears to be missing. I posted what I thought is the culprit.

Comment: @AlanWeibel I tried to fix the modulus arithmetic; try the edited version.